# I was updating my pokemon go and it said i had to delete it then log back in.

Tags: pokemon-go

Now it doesn't recognise my email address so i cannot log in again.  please help.  how do i log back in to my account, or has anyone had the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You are probably logging into the wrong account. There is one for google and a completely different one for pokemon. You can choose to create an account with either one, but they are not the same thing. So if it don't work on google try the pokemon account, which is where you probably created it or vice versa.